# Verificar data atual automaticamente

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estou desenvolvendo um sistema em `PHP` em que: Disponibilizo uma página de concurso de inscrição para o pessoal, mas essa página tem um tempo de término, exemplo: A página ficará disponível a partir de hoje 08/05/18 :17:11 e irá desaparecer no dia 09/05/18 23:59:00. Sei que consigo capturar a data e hora atual no `mysql` usando o seguinte select: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');`. Preciso de alguma forma comparar essa data com a data especificada no término do concurso e ao chegar no horário determinado, não exibir mais o mesmo.

Não postei código pois realmente não consegui desenvolver nada, preciso de uma luz de como prosseguir. Estou desenvolvendo o sistema em `PHP` puro, sem framework. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça uma condição no `WHERE` da `query`:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM [table]
WHERE [campo_data_expiracao] < NOW()
```

Algo assim. Qualquer coisa poste sua estrutura da tabela para que eu possa ser mais específico na resposta.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado!

Comment: Exemplo de consulta: `SELECT * FROM nome_tabela WHERE  data_final < DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');`

Comment: Não precisa formatar a data o NOW() já retorna a data correta =)

Comment: Sim, mas preciso da hora também, o now só retorna a data e não horário.

Comment: @JorgeMatheus deve ter algo errado na config do seu `MySQL` então, porque o `NOW()` deve retornar data e hora.

'The NOW() function returns the current date and time.'

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_now.asp

Comment: Realmente, havia. Obrigado!